# Drools rule for minimization - any other way?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

i have a [Meeting Scheduing](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#meetingScheduling)-like system. i'm minimizing the number of rooms used in it the following way:

```
rule "minimize #rooms used"
when
    $room : Room()
    exists MeetingAssignment(room==$room, meeting!=null)
then scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -10);  
end
```

so, in the end, OptaPlanner will rather go for a room that's already assigned a meeting than a fresh one.

is there another/better way of doing this? i'm combining many rules in the backend-- the rules i have don't have "side-effects" (updates, etc.) 
on one-another, so this is doable. and i want less number of rules for speed-performance. i don't see a way to merge this rule into other(s).

any ideas?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

A) Yes, there is: **anti load balancing**. In the docs, look for the chapter on **Fairness** (AKA load balancing) and invert the score impact of that.

This will incentivize it to cram as much as possible meetings in the same room, draining low-used rooms first, even if it doesn't drain the low-used room immediately (it makes it easier to do that later).
The catch22 is when you want to do load balancing within the minimum number of rooms...

B) Or don't do A) and introduce coarse-grained moves that deplete rooms. Start with adding pillar change moves - but that's definitely not enough because they don't spread out the load of that depleting room (it all lands in the same room).